# materialize model not working

Tags: javascript, materialize

I was looking through the docs of materializecss. But the modal seems not working. I just used the code that was in the docs http://materializecss.com/modals.html

**Html**

```
<!-- Modal Trigger -->
  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
     $('#modal1').modal('open');
  });
```

I had put a pen as well

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/flyingboy007/pen/peoZRE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs - initialising `.modal()` allows on-click to function properly on the anchor.

```
$('#modal1').modal()
```

you'll get the modal to show onclick - (trying to debug for on ready)

--- update ---
on Codepen, there's a weird delay:
I got it work in `$(document).ready` by using

```
$('#modal1').modal().modal('open');
```

(It's not an elegant solution, but it seems to work);

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/denistsoi/pen/oZNMdJ)

Answer (score 0):

use `.show()` for displaying elements with jQuery.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#modal1').show();
  });
```

**OR** on click

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Modal</a>

$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  $('.modal').show();
});
```

Comment: why the basic html didnt work?? It should trigger on click with the document.ready right?

Comment: eventhough this works I think this feels like a hack.